# IPointerClickHandler not working since class implements Singleton

Tags: unity-game-engine, singleton, abstract-class, raycasting

I had setup an `IPointerClickHandler` that was working perfectly fine before I decided to change the structure of my project and make this class a Singleton.

Since then the function `OnPointerClick()` never gets trigger.

Some guy was explaining that a bug can occur when the class has a parent and that we should also add `IPointerDownHandler` and `IPointerUpHandler` in order to get it to work but that didn't do the job.

```
public class PlaceTowers : Singleton<PlaceTowers>, IPointerClickHandler, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler
```

I've also tried to send the data from the Singleton to the **PlaceTowers** class like that but the `OnPointClick()` of the Singleton also doesn't get trigger.

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
    {

        public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
        {
            Debug.Log("In singleton");
            PlaceTowers.i.OnPointerClick(eventData);
        }


        private static T I;

        public static T i
        {
            get
            {
                if (I == null)
                {
                    I = FindObjectOfType<T>();
                }
                return I;
            }
        }

    }
```

Any idea on how to trigger IPointerClickHandler ?

Answer (score 0):

Check the `abstract` meaning in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/abstract). An abstract class is like a master parent class for other classes to inherit from. An abstract class cannot be instantiated.
I would try implementing `OnPointerClick` in `PlaceTowers` and make sure that the implementation is on an instance class that is not abstract. Also I would make sure that the instance is created and in the scene.
Check in the [documentation](https://docs.unity3d.com/2019.1/Documentation/ScriptReference/EventSystems.IPointerClickHandler.html) how its implemented in a monobevaviour. Also check that you meet all the conditions that are mentioned in the docs such as to ensure an Event System exists.
Find below not debugged suggested pseudo-code suggested.

```
public abstract class Singleton<T> : MonoBehaviour where T : MonoBehaviour
{
    private static T I;

    public static T i
    {
        get
        {
            if (I == null)
            {
                I = FindObjectOfType<T>();
            }
            return I;
        }
    }
}

public class PlaceTowers : Singleton<PlaceTowers>, IPointerClickHandler, 
IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler {
    public void OnPointerClick(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        Debug.Log("In singleton");
        PlaceTowers.i.OnPointerClick(eventData);
    }
}
```